# Elasticsearch deleted document reappears using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running ES on single node cluster for development.
I am deleting a document using delete api from kibana. It is deleted for a second and immediately reappears. Any help would be appreciated

Here is api command I use:

1. DELETE test/_doc/12345

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "12345",
  "_version" : 231,
  "result" : "deleted",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 899,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

2. GET test/_count

```
{
  "count" : 3,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

3. Immediately deleted doc is re-indexed
   GET test/_count

```
{
  "count" : 4,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
Check your "_version" : 231, <--- you may have a process that use the same id and always add it! 
Without deleting it if the _version increase it mean that something is adding again and again the same document. You need to give more information about how your data are saved in elastic.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, yes the "_version" is increasing. I use logstash piepline to load data to elastic. 
`
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/config/postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://${host}:${port}/${db}"
    jdbc_user => "${user}"
    jdbc_password => "${pass}"
 schedule => "*/10 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from test where date>=CURRENT_DATE AND modificationdate > :sql_last_value;"
    clean_run => true
 jdbc_fetch_size => 10000
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was an data issue. my logstash jdbc statement checks for modificationdate greater than sql_last_value. and scheduler is set to run every 10 seconds. The reappeared documents have  modificationdate in the future, changing it to current date solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> ...If clean_run is set to true, this value will be ignored and
>   sql_last_value will be set to Jan 1, 1970

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_state

That may explain why all your data are added each 10 minutes. Remove the clean_run and test again or check if the _version filed is updated.

Comment: thank you Gabriel for your prompt response to my query, however found that it was an data issue on my database